# drupal issue with install profile and domain module?

Tags: drupal, makefile, drupal-7, settings, drush

I had generated the make file with the contrib module domain.
When we enable the domain module, we just want to append the following code to the settings.php file.

```
include_once DRUPAL_ROOT.'/profiles/my_profile/modules/contrib/domain/settings.inc';
```

When I try to install this profile, I get an error

> Fatal error: Undefined function domain_get_primary_table()

this happens because when we install a profile the settings.php file overwrites the included settings.inc. So when we try to install the domain module it gives the above error and stops installation.
Anyone have an idea how can we install the profile along with the domain module without this issue.

Comment: did you trye adding that line to default.settings.php before the install?

Comment: @Pinoniq - Thanks, i have fixed the issue..Now its working.

Comment: @John-php Please add your solution as the answer and accept it so folks in the future can benefit from it. Thanks